# Random walk always stays below a level $a$

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Suppose we have a random walk $S_n$ with i.i.d. steps $X_i$. We assume that
$$\mathbb{E}[X_i] = -\mu, \text{Var}[X_i] = 1,$$
where $\mu$ is close (or going) to zero. We also assume that the moment generating function and its derivatives $M_{X_i}, M_{X_i}', M_{X_i}'', M_{X_i}'''$ are all bounded in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ by a constant $C$, where $\epsilon, C$ are independent of $\mu$ (which is going to zero).

Fix a constant $a\geq 1$, are there any estimates in the literature for the probability of the random walk always stays below $a$, i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}\big\{{\max_{n\geq 0} S_n \leq a}\big\}?$$
(I believe the upper bound should be $Ca\mu$.)

For the special case where we replace $a$ by $0$, then
$$\mathbb{P}\big\{{\max_{n\geq 0} S_n \leq 0}\big\} \leq C\mu$$
which essentially follows from Sparre-Andersen theorem together with Berry-Esseen bound.

Comment: For the record: the only universal lower bound is clearly zero, as shown by the random walk with $X_i = a + 1$ with probability $1-\varepsilon$ and $X_i = -((1-\varepsilon)(a+1) + \mu)/\varepsilon$ with probability $\varepsilon$.

Comment: On a second thought, there is no non-trivial universal upper bound, too: just consider the trivial random walk with $X_i = -\mu$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki thank you for the remark, I added the assumption that $\text{Var}(X_i) >\delta$.

Comment: This can save the lower bound, but the upper bound still seems impossible: if $X_i = -1/\mu$ with probability $\mu^2$ and $X_i = 0$ otherwise, then $X_i$ has mean $-\mu$ and variance $1-\mu^2 \approx 1$, and still $S_n = 0$ almost surely.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks again! In my case, the $X_i$ is an explicit (continuous) distribution supported on $(-\infty, \infty)$, but I will think about a condition so that this can be stated with generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$p(a):=P\big(\max_{n\ge0} S_n\le a\big).$$
Assume that $c_3:=E|X_1-EX_1|^3<\infty$.

By the improvement by [Sakhanenko](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1119047) of Lemma 8 by [S. Nagaev](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tvp&paperid=1854&option_lang=eng) (the improvement consisting in removing an extra factor $c_3$) and trivial time-rescaling,
$$p(a)-p(0)\le C\mu(a+c_3)$$
for $\mu\ge0$ and $a\ge0$; everywhere here, $C$ denotes various universal positive real constants. Also, you know that $p(0)\le C\mu$. So, for all $a\ge c_3$
$$p(a)\le C\mu a.\tag{1}$$

---

Concerning a lower bound on $p(a)$, Corollary 1 to Theorem 16 of $\S$23 of the book by [Borovkov](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-9866-3#:%7E:text=The%20object%20of%20queueing%20theory,on%20the%20direction%20of%20investigation.) implies
$$p(a)\ge1-e^{-Qa} \tag{2}$$
for $a\ge0$, where $Q:=\sup\{t\colon M(t)\le1\}$, $M(t):=Ee^{tX}$, and $X:=X_1$.

If e.g. $|X|\le b$ almost surely for some real $b>0$, then for all $t\in[0,Q]$ we have $M''(t)=EX^2e^{tX}\le b^2 M(t)\le b^2$, by the convexity of $M$. So, $1=M(Q)\le M(0)+M'(0)Q+b^2Q^2/2=1-\mu Q+b^2Q^2/2$, whence $Q\ge c\mu$, where $c:=\frac2{b^2}$. If now $Qa$ is large, then (2) implies $p(a)\approx1$, so that the lower bound in (2) is as good as it can be. If, finally, $Qa$ is not large, then the lower bound in (2) is $\asymp Qa\ge c\mu a$, which matches (1).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I am interested in when $\mu\to 0$. So the constants can not implicitly depend on the step distribution $F$; they can certainly depend on $c_3$ since I can control this quantity while sending $\mu$ to zero. With a quick look over the paper, it seems that it doesn't use things like KMT coupling where the constants implicitly depend on $F$ that we have no control over. I will look more carefully at the papers, in case you can already spot a place where the constants might implicitly depend on $F$, I would really appreciate if you could point it out : )

Comment: @Xiao : As is stated in the answer, the constants $C$ are universal, and the dependence on the distribution of $X_1$ is only as follows: to get (1), we need to require that $a\ge c_3$ -- or, more generally, that $a\ge c_3/C$ for some universal positive real constant $C$.